# How to encrpt/decrypt data in janusGraph?

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph

I'm trying to migrate neo4j data to janusGraph. In neo4j, there's an approach to implement customized function to encrypt/decrypt data. Is janusGraph has similar feature to support it? I checked the documentation of janusGraph but never found of this part.
Thanks for helps!

Comment: JanusGraph supports various storage backends like Cassandra and ElasticSearch. If you are looking for encryption at rest, then why not configure them in the storage system you choose.